# Запрос для вывода максимального результата

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Вывожу всю информацию о первом пользователе.

```
$user_info = DB::table('user')->take(1)->get();
return view('statistic', ['user_info' => $user_info]);
```

В шаблоне

```
@foreach($user_info as $user)
{{$user->id}}
{{$user->nick}}
{{$user->lvl}}
@endforeach
```

А как вывести информацию о скажем 10 пользователях в порядке убывания по размеру lvl-уровня?

Получается вывести только само значение без остальной информации.

```
$user_info = DB::table('user')->get()->max('lvl');
return view('statistic', ['user_info' => $user_info]);
```

Через foreach не получается остальную информацию вывести о пользователе, а только само одно значение

```
{{$user_info}} 99 lvl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать так:

```
DB::table('user')->orderBy('lvl', 'desc')->limit(10)->get();
```

В шаблоне можно оставить:

```
@foreach($user_info as $user)
{{$user->id}}
{{$user->nick}}
{{$user->lvl}}
@endforeach
```